# Problems updating using a subquery (join to the same table) using HQL over a MySQL database.

Tags: java, mysql, sql, hibernate, hql

I am trying to get what should be an easy update to set-up to work in Hibernate (using HQL) over a MySQL database.  There 
are other threads out there in regards to errors similar to what I have encountered but nothing that speaks to the same exact problem.

The update I am trying to do is to update a row with information from another row in the same table. Nothing special here and I have a similar version working in MySQL using Toad.

It is my understanding that HQL does not like inner joins for updates and that a sub-query is to be used instead - do I have that right?

Well anyways, below is the first version of the update I worked with.  This threw the error message 
"Invalid path: 'tbB.column1'" and looking at the below I am not sure where the problem lies.

```
UPDATE tableA tbA
   SET tbA.column1 = tbB.column1
     WHERE tbA.operationalId =
          (SELECT tbB.operationalId FROM tableA AS tbB
            WHERE tbA.operationalId = tbB.operationalId)
   AND tbA.column2 = 1
```

Further researching this issue, I replaced the above listed 'set' statement with a straight 
assignment of a value to tbA.column1 and encountered a different error which is listed below.

error = "You can't specify target table 'tableA' for update in FROM clause"

```
UPDATE tableA tbA
   SET tbA.column1 = 1
     WHERE tbA.operationalId =
          (SELECT tbB.operationalId FROM tableA AS tbB
            WHERE tbA.operationalId = tbB.operationalId)
   AND tbA.column2 = 1
```

If anyone can point me in the right direction that would be appreciated - I am not sure if the sql needs to be further adjusted to run successfully in Hibernate.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL supports `join` in `update`.  I'm not sure if hibernate does:

```
UPDATE tableA tbA join
       tableA tblB
       on tbA.operationalId = tbB.operationalId
   SET tbA.column1 = tbB.column1
   WHERE tbA.column2 = 1;
```

Comment: Yes I am able to get it to work in MySQL, just not Hibernate and there lies my challenge.